# Filling in a missing portion of a truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following truth table:
$$
\boxed{
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
a & b & c & x \\ \hline
F & F & F         & F \\
F & F & T         & F \\
F & T & F         & F \\
F & T & T         & F \\
T & F & F         & T \\
T & F & T         & T \\
T & T & F         & F \\
T & T & T         & T 
\end{array}}
$$

I am supposed to use any logical operator: and, or, not. I tried like $10$ formulas already, and I am not able to think of what combination of $a,b,c$ will get that $x$ column right. Have I missed something really silly?

Comment: Please edit you question and describe what you have already tried.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form . $x$ appears to be $a$ and ((not $b$) or $c$)

Comment: I remember that a cousin of mine, an electrical engineer, used a visualization of `x` in the form of one or several matrices to visually find blocks that indicate which logical operators (logic gates) may be used to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

$x$ is only True in rows 5, 6, and 8, all of which have $a$ as True.  This means that we should look for:

$x$ = $a$ ∧ something

Whatever that "something" is, it should return True for all combinations of $b$ and $c$ except for $b$ True and $c$ False (which was row 7, where $x$ is False).

Answer (score 1):

because there are fewer $f$ than $t$'s, i will look at 
$$\begin{align}x &= ab'c'+ab'c++abc\\
&=ab'(c+c')+abc\\
&=ab'+abc\\
&=a(b'+bc)\\
&=a(b'+c)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about what it means to find a formula $x$ that fits the truth table. The easiest way to generate such a formula is simply to **write a disjunction of all the cases where you want $x$ to be true**.

Essentially, $x$ will say "I am true when this combination of $A$, $B$ and $C$ occurs, or when that one occurs, or when that one occurs, etc.". What you have to do is look up the lines where $x$ is true, get the corresponding truth values of $A$, $B$ and $C$, connect them with a conjunction, and link everything up with disjunctions.

By looking at the three lines where $x$ is true, you get:
$$x:=(A\land\neg B\land\neg C)\lor(A\land\neg B\land C)\lor(A\land B\land C)$$
Make sure you understand what this means and how the truth table follows.

Now, any other formula fitting the truth table will be equivalent to $x$. For instance, we can "improve" $x$ by noticing that it requires $A$ to always be true, such that we can take it out of the parentheses:
$$x=A\land\big((\neg B\land\neg C)\lor(\neg B\land C)\lor(B\land C)\big)$$
The part inside the big brackets is listing three out of four possible cases for the truth values of the pair $(B,C)$. In fact, the missing case is $(B\land\neg C)$, so that we can rewrite this segment to say "any combination of $B$ and $C$ works, except for $(B\land\neg C)$. We do so using a negation:
$$x=A\land\neg(B\land\neg C)$$
And this is the most succinct expression of $x$ using only the connectives $\left\{\land,\neg\right\}$. Furthermore, you can compare it to the truth table: $x$ is true whenever $A$ is true except for the specific case where $B$ is true and $C$ is false. This corresponds precisely to the last four lines of the table, without the penultimate.

Answer (score -2):

**Hint:**

> $$x\equiv a\land(\neg b\lor c).$$

How did I come up with this? Well, if $a$ is false, then any conjunction with $a\land(\text{something here})$ will be false as well. That takes care of the top half of the truth table. All that is left, then, is to figure out how to manipulate a combination of $b$ and $c$ to combine with $a$ to give the desired truth values. Thus, what you want is what is given above (grayed out in case you want to try to deduce it yourself).

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain?

Comment: Thanks. But, I cannot use an implication. Only and, or, not.

Comment: If my answer is wrong, then please do let me know instead of just anonymous downvotes. That gives me no chance to correct.

Comment: @abdulkareemsyed You can easily modify what I have provided to get rid of the implication symbol since $p\to q\equiv \neg p\lor q$. Do you see it?

Comment: I did not downvote, but "how did you get this formula?"

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin The downvotes are idiotic--this is a correct answer. The reasoning is fairly straightforward: if $a$ is false, then any conjunction with $a\land (\text{something here})$ will be false as well. That takes care of the top part. All that is left, then, is to figure out how to manipulate a combination of $b$ and $c$ to combine with $a$ to give the desired truth values. Thus, what you want is $x\equiv a\land(\neg b\lor c)$. I find the downvotes to be quite baffling.

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter) but it would probably help your answer if you moved this very helpful comment to the answer itself.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but maybe it got a down vote because it just gives the answer with no explanation.

Comment: @TravisJ I suspect the downvoters either 1) did not understand my answer, or 2) just don't care and like to downvote things. Also, I oftentimes try to make answers more or less commensurate with the effort put forth by the OP, in which this case is nil. My answer is really more of a "hint."

Comment: @MagicMan, I totally agree (and see your point).  I only suggested moving it since you already took the time to write it (many people may not read the comments).  It is a slick answer.

Comment: @TravisJ I appreciate your kind words. :) At this point, I'm afraid I don't care much anymore. The OP's comment "Thanks. But, I cannot use an implication. Only and, or, not." is a rather clear indicator that s/he is more interested in simply obtaining a valid answer than actually trying to learn anything at all. I'll leave my answer though because it is correct...alas and alack, the mystery of voting patterns will never be made evident...*c'est la vie*